# Automatic Reference Counting in Cocoa-touch - inline best practice

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

Before the ARC was in place for ios development, i have been using something like this in `viewDidLoad` to setup my navigation items:

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)] autorelease];`

How can i implement this correctly while ARC is enabled for my view controller while keeping it a 1 line deal?

I know about prepending the __autoreleasing, __strong, etc, but i don't see how i can create this `rightBarButtonItem` without separating it into 2 lines like this:

```
__autoreleasing UIBarButtonItem *rightBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarItem;
```

Comment: `__autoreleasing` should not be used in this way. The place to use `__autoreleasing` is for out-parameters as is often seen in `NSError **` i.e. `- (NSString *)doSomethingWithError:(NSError **)error` becomes `- (NSString *)doSomethingWithError:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use __autoreleasing qualifier in this situation. The rightBarButtonItem has a strong reference for the assigned object, and then the assigned object will be automatically released when the rightBarButtonItem is released (when UINavigationBar is released).

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)];
```